# How to redirect to source path of a next.js website that uses rewrites

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I have set up rewrites due to how the website is deployed I want the user to access particular path and be redirected to a url that has actual content:

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
        {
            source: '/one/:slug*',
            destination: '/:slug*'
        },
        {
            source: '/two/:slug*',
            destination: '/:slug*'
        },
        {
            source: '/three/:slug*',
            destination: '/:slug*'
        },
        {
            source: '/four/:slug*',
            destination: '/:slug*'
        }
     ]
  }
```

So for example user accesses `my_url.com/four` he would be getting the content from `my_url.com`. Same with other paths.
The issue is that I have redirect button on page:

```
        <button
            onClick={() => {
                window.location.href = '/';
            }}
        >
            Redirect
        </button>
```

Now is it possible to redirect to the current "rewritten" source URL path that is setup in rewrites so I dont need to hardcode the intended redirect path onto the button?

So lets say if I was on `my_url.com/four/0218309120/content` after clicking the button I want to be redirected to `my_url.com/four` not to `my_url.com/`